# Function not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++

So here's my code. It's telling me that partition isn't declared when I call it in kSmall... Any ideas?

```
int kSmall(int A[], int k, int low, int high){
    int pivot = A[(low+high)/2];
    int idx = partition(A, pivot, low, high);
    if(idx-low+1>k)
        kSmall(A,k,low,idx-1);
    else if(idx-low+1<k)
        kSmall(A,k,idx+1,high);
    else
        return A[idx];
}

int partition(int A[], int p, int low, int high){
    int temp;
    int left = low;
    int right = high;
    while (left < right){
        while (A[left]<p)
            left++;
        while (A[right]>p)
            right--;
        if (left<right){
            temp = A[left];
            A[left] = A[right];
            A[right] = temp;
            }
    }
    return left;
}
```

The exact error is: main.cpp:36:43: error: ‘partFunc’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

If you define partition() before kSmall()  in your cpp file main.cpp issue will be resolved.

Comment: when learning c++, I also try to rearrange the method, but If you havemany method, you'll be crazy.haha I forgot the term, but I think you can define all of your method before the actual method code blocks so you wont be bother is your calling method is already defined. @user3434233

Comment: @Nin-ya previous declaration is mandatory, so if you define function  in advance of using it is a declaration and definition

Comment: I think I found what am I saying here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296924/how-to-order-functions-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the function `partition()` before the function in which you are calling it.

Simply add this line:

```
int partition(int[], int, int , int );
```

before `kSmall`. This is because kSmall() calls partition(), it gives an error as there is no partition() function before it, so you can either define the function before it, or simply provide a prototype.